# Redirect to a SubDomain

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, redirect

I'm using Yellowtree's GEOIP-Detect plugin in order to redirect visitors to pages based upon their location. However I cannot get the code to completely work. The code first grabs the users IP and then the info from the IP is stored in a multidimensional array. The variable $statecode plucks out the state listed and then switch is called upon based upon what state array is pulled.

I then move over to Javascript in order to attempt to redirect the visitor from the current page to the new page. The Script migrates over the PHP Variable so that it can read correctly in JS and then a function attempts to redirect the page using window.location.replace which is what I read will only work in Chrome, and then as a failsafe window.location for other browsers. However, nothing happens. Where did I go wrong?

```
<?php 
if (function_exists('geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip')){
    $userInfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
    $stateCode = $userInfo->subdivisions->isoCode;
    switch ($stateCode) {
        case 'AL':
        $url = 'subdomain1.domain.tld';
        break;
        case 'AR':
        $url = 'subdomain2.domain.tld';
        break;
        default:
        $url = 'subdomain3.domain.tld';
    }   
    if ($url) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var url = <?php echo $url ?>;
        function(){
            try { window.location.replace(url); } 
            catch(e) { window.location = url; }
        }
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: What's wrong with `if ($url) { header("Location: $url"); exit; }`?

Comment: When i used header(Loc..... it would not replace the original domain.com and would only add $url to the end. Example  domain.tld/subdomain.domain.tld instead of subdomain.domain.tld

Comment: Sorry, you would need `header("Location: http://$url")`

Comment: Ah, okay that I did not try. Adding the http:// before $url worked. Submit as an answer and I'll mark it closed. Thx Nick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the redirection directly in PHP by sending a `Location` header. Note that you need to prepend `http://` to `$url` so that it doesn't get treated as a relative path to the current URL.

```
if ($url) { 
    header("Location: http://$url"); 
    exit; 
}
```

Comment: Redirect from Javascript Ajax in PHP *not* works.

Comment: @TheAlphaGhost that's correct, you would need to pass a new URL back in the Ajax response, and then use `window.location` to change the address